# What is the maximum nesting depth in yaml?

Tags: yaml

I am writing some yaml templates for configs, and they beginning to have many degrees of nesting.

What is the maximum possible, and maximum recommended nesting depth in yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of YAML 1.2, the only limit imposed by the spec is 1024 characters on implicit keys:

```yaml
foo: bar                                # okay
[ foo ]: bar                            # also okay
<<more-than-1024-characters-here>>: bar # not okay
```

This is forbidden regardless of whether the key is a scalar (first line) or a collection node (second line). Therefore, it practically limits nesting in implicit keys. However, you can simply use explicit keys instead:

```yaml
? foo
: bar
? [ foo ]
: bar
? <<more-than-1024-characters-here>>
: bar
```

Apart from this, you do not need to be concerned about nesting as handwritten files are very unlikely to reach limits imposed by an implementation. You could of course test the implementation you use for its limits, e.g. PyYAML:

```py
import yaml, traceback
from yaml.constructor import ConstructorError

for i in range(128, 1024):
    open, close = "", ""
    for j in range(0, i):
        open, close = open + "[", close + "]"

    try: yaml.load(open + close)
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        print("failed at depth " + str(i))
        exit(1)
```

This yields (after some time):

```
[…]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
failed at depth 496
```

A possible depth of 495 levels seems to be plenty.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit to nesting in YAML.

But there can be limits in the software you use it with, most often you'll run into either memory or CPU limits. I'm not aware of any recent libraries that have hard limits, unless you start to run into limits happening because of indents overflowing an integer ;-)